# How to get an outline effect on text in SVG?

Tags: svg

I just want a simple SVG image that has some arbitrary text on an angle, which I can do.  Thing is, I also want the text to have a sort of "outline" effect.  Like rather than a solid D, the inside and outside edges of the letter D are drawn with a line of a specified thickness and the rest of the D isn't drawn at all, so as to look almost "hollow".

Can SVG do this?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Yes it can ;-)

I tried to realize that with [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org) and then edited the source of the svg-File.
Just don't fill it and use a stroke with color and width to draw it.
I got that:

```html
<text x="100" y="100" id="text2383" xml:space="preserve" style="font-size:56px;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1;font-family:Bitstream Vera Sans">
<tspan x="100" y="100" id="tspan2385">D</tspan></text>
```

The interesting part is in the "style" attribute.

```
"fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1;"
```

Comment: Sweet.  I managed to get this out of Inkscape too (rather than editing XML, which is cool).

Comment: Just FYI, a lot of the styles included by inkscape are _usually_ redundant (in that they are the default). For the style attribute above, you could probably get away with:

`"fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1px;"`

You could likely also omit `stroke:#000000` if you were actually using black.

Comment: While your answer is helpful, it's incredibly difficult to read. It'd really help to separate the style entries on separate lines so we can actually read what you're trying to do

Answer (score 79):

paint-order: stroke; worked wonders for me in this D3 chart I'm working on.

My final css:

```
.name-text {
    font-size:  18px;
    paint-order: stroke;
    stroke: #000000;
    stroke-width: 1px;
    stroke-linecap: butt;
    stroke-linejoin: miter;
    font-weight: 800;
}
```

My source (scroll down just a bit):
https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/painting.html#PaintOrderProperty

Comment: paint-order: stroke is not supported on IE. is there any tip/trick to support this on IE?

Comment: @cletus, This should be the accepted answer, because the one you accepted does not actually allow a fill _with stroke_, AFAICT, whereas this answer does.

Comment: Thanks! Removing irrelevants it comes down to something like this: `text {
    paint-order: stroke;
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 10px;
}`

Comment: See [SVG 2: paint-order attribute](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/single-page.html#painting-PaintOrderProperty) (the SVG 2 implementation seems to be [in progress](https://chromestatus.com/feature/5760616295825408) in major browsers).

Answer (score 22):

You can use a `<filter>` for this, more specifically a combination with `<feMorphology>`:

```html
<svg style="height:100px;width:100%;background-color:Green">

<defs>
<filter id="whiteOutlineEffect" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
  <feMorphology in="SourceAlpha" result="MORPH" operator="dilate" radius="2" />
  <feColorMatrix in="MORPH" result="WHITENED" type="matrix" values="-1 0 0 0 1, 0 -1 0 0 1, 0 0 -1 0 1, 0 0 0 1 0"/>
  <feMerge>
    <feMergeNode in="WHITENED"/>
    <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
  </feMerge>
</filter>
</defs>

<g>
  <text x="10" y="50" fill="black" font-size="60" filter="url(#whiteOutlineEffect)">
    Example
  </text>
</g>

</svg>
```

You might have to tune the `x`/`y`/`width`/`height` attributes of the filter in order to adapt the filter canvas size, see also [Humongous height value for <filter> not preventing cutoff](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46120700/2261442) or [Gaussian blur cutoff at edges](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6555600/2261442).

I also created an interactive [d3.js](https://d3js.org/)-powered demo to compare different solutions presented in this thread here with various settings to play around: https://bl.ocks.org/Herst/d5db2d3d1ea51a8ab8740e22ebaa16aa

Comment: @زياد iOS webkit might have some bugs in that regards (I remember that it has issues with `paint-order: stroke;` and certain animations using transformations). If you have a small testcase then it would be please report it it to the Webkit team.

Comment: Yes I think it is a bug in iOS .. The text becomes blurry when using this filter in iPhone.

Comment: @زياد It's been a year. Do you by any chance know whether that is still the case in newer iOS versions?

Comment: Hello! Sorry I don't have any working iOS device right now, I moved to Android.

Answer (score 10):

Graphical objects in SVG can have a fill (black by default) and a stroke (none by default).  If you want to have red outline on your text, then set fill="none" and stroke="red".  You might want to also tweak the value of the stroke-width property.

Comment: That is cool, and easy - but for things that have interior shapes (like a FontAwesome icon) it strokes the inside as well as the boundary. Logical, but annoying.

Answer (score 5):

Another example for outlines and glows is given here: http://www.w3.org/People/Dean/svg/texteffects/index.html

```
<svg width="350" height="75" viewBox="0 0 350 75"><title>MultiStroke</title><rect x="0" y="0" width="350" height="75" style="fill: #09f"/><g style="overflow:hidden; text-anchor: middle; font-size:45; font-weight: bold; font-family: Impact"><text x="175" y="55" style="fill: white; stroke: #0f9; stroke-width: 14">
    Stroked Text
    </text><text x="175" y="55" style="fill: white; stroke: #99f; stroke-width: 8">
    Stroked Text
    </text><text x="175" y="55" style="fill: white; stroke: black; stroke-width: 2">
    Stroked Text
    </text></g>
</svg>
```

Comment: On Firefox this does not look as good at if things are smaller (e.g. inside a group with `transform` with `scale()`),the outline appears uneven, perhaps a precision issue.