# Gaussian blur cutoff at edges

Tags: svg, svg-filters

I am working on an svg export utility for a drawing program on android. I am having a problem that the behind blur is cutoff past the shape boundaries - looks like i need to resize the viewBox or increase the margin or something. Does anyone know the best way?

The test file url is [here](http://www.robmunro.net/misc/test.svg) - it downloads as the mime type isn't setup correctly on the server and I cant restart it at the moment :(. There are embedded images and fonts in the file, Which is why it's big. But if you save it to disk you can open in chrome, ff, etc...

An enlarged example of this problem is given. Notice the square edges on the orange glow.

[image]

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The filter canvas has default values : x=y=-10% and width=height=120%. You can change them with the x, y, width and height attributes on the filter element.

Try to set a bigger canvas :

```
<filter x="-50%" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%"/>
```

Yet, since the canvas is bigger, there will be performance loss.

Comment: Seems to have no effect for me.

Comment: Oops, nevermind, I was applying the attributes on the feGuassianBlur element, not on the filter element. It works.

Comment: Tried applying the attributes to the filter element.  Has no effect on the blur being cut off for me.

Comment: Thanks mate I was reading all the documentation I could find on this and nothing worked... I am still wrapping my head around SVG and every time I think I have it some problem like that pops up and I lose it... it is so simple to fix the problem after you figure it out so thanks for the -50% x and y position. because many say add to width and height but noone said oh yeah move the start position of the filter to avoid trimmimg. @Tangui Thanks ! You are able to explain a problem in few words

Comment: this information is gold. I wasn't reading anywhere else about the possibility to enlarge the render area of a filter.

Comment: If you're trying to do this in inline SVG in HTML, Safari has a bug where the filter doesn't make the whole svg element larger, so the cutoff is still there. The solution is to add an invisible element into the SVG (e.g. rect with fill-opacity="0") with the same x/y/width/height attributes.