# accessible d3 text in high contrast

Tags: css, d3.js, high-contrast

I have a simple donut chart that I created using d3. My code is very simple and I have a text inside the donut chart that I added using `<text>` element. Something similar like this example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/juan-cb/1984c7f2b446fffeedde), but much simpler.

```
         var style = {
                'font-size': fontSize,
                'text-anchor': 'middle'
            };

            svg.append("text")
                .attr("dy", dy)
                .style(style)
                .attr("class", "dataText")
                .text("100%");
        }
```

Everything works fine, however when I tested in Windows high contrast mode (alt + left shift + Print screen) **this text** doesn't show up.
If I change my text to yellow, this will show in high contrast. However, for normal user, I need this to be black.

What I tried so far:
1) I tried to detect high contrast mode using @media query suggested in [here](https://css-tricks.com/accessible-svgs-high-contrast-mode/) and change fill color to be yellow during high contrast mode only, but seems like FF has a bug about this.
2) From this [link](http://www.slideshare.net/TheZero1/webexpo-highcontrast), they suggested to set color / border to be transparent. No luck still.

Anyone encountered this issue before? What did you do to make this accessible? I tried to open NVD3 (using D3) examples page in high contrast and looks like they are having issue for their text element as well.

Pie chart in normal mode:
[image: normal mode]

Pie chart in high contrast mode (text doesn't show):
[image]

Comment: I am a bit confused. How can you show the black color on a black background? Is it supposed to not show the text. Am i missing something here?

Comment: Usually for span or label, if their color is black, windows high contrast will convert it to yellow (by default) not with text element though.

Comment: Why don't you give the text a white shadow, it will always be visible, and in case of white background it will not be visible. Can you try? This might solve your issue for now.

Comment: if you can share the code then i can play with it.

Comment: @hunzaboy actually white shadow/border might work. Let me try :)

Comment: @hunzaboy I ended up adding white-outline. A bit hacky, but for normal user they don't see it (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442164/how-to-get-an-outline-effect-on-text-in-svg) A good workaround, thanks!